# How to run Sequential Jobs using job schedule in Sql server

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis, ssms-2014

I have a requirement that i need to run multiple jobs in a sequence. Let's say I have 20 jobs which already existed. These jobs are depending on each other. Right now i am running these jobs manually like below

run Job1 --> run job2 upon Job1 Success/quit next process upon Job1 failure --> run job3 upon Job2 Success/quit next process upon Job2 failure --> .... run job20 upon Job19 Success/quit next process upon Job19 failure --> Quit the job.

Along with this i want to have log history for these all jobs. If any job failed in mid way i want to check the log to find which job got failed and what is the reason for the fail.

Now i want to make it automatic. Is there a possible way to do it?

Please help me

Thank you in advance
Chandana

Comment: One way is just use sp_start_job.  Add a step to each job, make sure it's the last step and have it execute "exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'<<Name of next job to start>>'

Comment: @TimMylott's comment is the "standard" way to do this. Tim, if you make that an answer, I'd up vote it. Sometimes even a short answer is the right answer.

Comment: @EricBrandt answer added, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I assume when you say "job" you mean a SQL Server Agent Job.

One way to accomplish what you are after is to simply use [sp_start_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) stored procedure.

1. On each job add a tsql job step.
2. Make sure it is the last step
3. Then have it execute the code below

   > EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'Name of Next Job to Start'

Here is a visual of that setup:
[image]

You can then daisy change the jobs and have the last step of Job2 start Job3 and so on...

Comment: Way to flesh that out. Good visuals.

Comment: In this case, if Job 2 fails then it will start job 1 again or starts from job 2 ?

Comment: It would quit and start from step 1 next time it is ran. You can also manually run it from SSMS and decide what step to start from.

Answer (score 0):

you can use maintenance plan.

in this feather you can set any job for step by step OR set `If` statement .

in this picture i show you a Incomplete display of maintenance plan :
[image]

> To create or manage maintenance plans, you must be a member of the
>   sysadmin fixed server role. Object Explorer only displays the
>   Maintenance Plans node for users who are members of the sysadmin fixed
>   server role.

you can read [HOW TO CREATE A MAINTENANCE PLAN HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/maintenance-plans/create-a-maintenance-plan-maintenance-plan-design-surface?view=sql-server-ver15)